# Limit of p-series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I was reading a text from Real Analysis and it claims that

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 1^{+}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^p}=k\quad \text{for some } k\in\mathbb{R}$$

What is the value of $k$?

Comment: This limit diverges to $+\infty$.  The Riemann zeta function has a pole at $1$.  When someone quotes "a text" without revealing the identity of the text, we often find that the person quoting was the one mistaken.  But, of course, in this case we cannot tell who was mistaken.

Comment: Yes, either the book is wrong, or you are misreading the book.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the problem is in fact
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 1^{+}}\left( (p-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^p}\right)=\lim_{p\rightarrow 1^{+}}\big( (p-1)\zeta(p)\big)$$

Since, close to $1$,
$$\zeta(p)=\frac{1}{p-1}+\gamma -\gamma _1(p-1) +O\left((p-1)^2\right)$$
$$(p-1)\zeta(p)=1+\gamma  (p-1)- \gamma _1(p-1)^2+O\left((p-1)^3\right)$$ which is a quite good approximation of the lhs for $0 \leq p\leq 2$.